# Error installing ADT plugin in Eclipse on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: android, eclipse, plugins, adt

I have installed the plugin many times before, but this time I keep getting this error:

[image: Install has encountered a problem]

> 'Install' has encountered a problem
>
> An error occurred while installing the items

Eclipse has some memory issues when running on my machine, so I just want to install the bare minimum plugins, etc.

Has anyone got any ideas how to get around this error?

**SOLVED**

I had the wrong version of Eclipse installed. I just installed the version from the Ubuntu software center and it didn't work, do I uninstalled it and downloaded the Java EE version from Eclipse's website and now it works.

Comment: I don't know if there's a log and where it's stored, but did you check /var/log/messages, and the Eclipse console, for more details?

Comment: It's ok now. Thanks for the reply though. I had the wrong version of Eclipse installed. I just installed the version from the Ubuntu software center and it didn't work, do I uninstalled it and downloaded the Java EE version from Eclipse's website and now it works. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: If you fix your own problem, its helpful if you post what you did as a solution, for future readers.

Comment: I did. Do you mean in the Original Post? I'll do that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the wrong version of Eclipse installed. I just installed the version from the Ubuntu software center and it didn't work, do I uninstalled it and downloaded the Java EE version from Eclipse's website and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Window* -> *preference* -> *Install/update* 
There update the plugin package ... the one responsible for installing ADT.
Worked for me atleast.